# read bash history via ssh does not work

Tags: bash, history

This does work:

```
server:~> history | tail -100   | grep etc
  908  2018-01-17 08:53:43 cd /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/default.d/
  ....
  ....
```

But this does not:

```
ssh root@server "history | tail -100 | grep etc"
```

Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently bash does not enable history handling when run non-interactively.

You can work around this by starting bash with the `-i` for interactive option:

```
ssh root@server "echo history | bash -i | tail -100 | grep etc"
```